# Running "real" IE8 / IE9 on Windows 8?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, windows-8, internet-explorer-9

On Windows 8, is there any way of running IE8 & 9 besides using rendering mode in IE10 or creating a virtual setup? As with previous versions of IE, IE10 doesn't seem to render 8 and 9 properly. Also tried IE Collection which won't install any of these versions on Windows 8.

Comment: (I think this is particular question is *on topic* here, as IE8/IE9 - in this context, which is specific about getting *accurate* behavior reproduction - can be viewed as *development tools* and thus this really isn't much different than "installing Visual Studio X" in "Windows Y" and/or under "constraint Z".)

Comment: +1 because supporting IE10 while also maintaining support for older versions is going to become a become a bigger problem for all of us in the very near future.

Comment: I just don't see myself running XP, Win 7 and Win 8 because I need to view IE7, IE8/9 and IE10 respectively (in "native mode"). There needs to be a software solution for this that will require only one OS.

Comment: it's possible to get IE6/7/8/9 all running together in Win7, using tools like IETester. I don't think it's possible to run IE10 alongside them though; you're going to need a Win7 VM I think. But at least you can get away without having to have an XP VM as well. In any case, I wouldn't bother supporting IE7 now; it's usage has fallen to pretty much the same as IE6 - just hovering above zero.

Comment: @Spudley "I wouldn't bother supporting IE7" - unless, of course, your clients are US government agencies - this is *my* reality :(

Comment: @pst - well yes... govt agencies do live in a different reality. But if you're supporting them with an IE7 app, the odds are you won't need to support IE10 any time soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible due to programmatic differences and dependencies Microsoft creates (for whatever reason).  The typical alternatives are to install a Virtual Machine ([Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/), or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or [VmWare Desktop Products](http://www.vmware.com/products/desktop_virtualization/)) with XP or W7 and have a Virutal Machine for each unique IE version you need.

**Update**

Anyone using Windows 8, Virtual PC has been renamed to the server version Hyper-V, comes with Windows 8 by default, and is not installed by default.

**Update 2**

I'd also recommend taking a look at https://www.browserstack.com/. It's a very nice product (I have no affiliation with that company, I've only used the product with much success).

Comment: "IE Tester" worked pretty well under Windows 7 .. there might be a Windows 8 version of it.

Comment: what a hell, I remember that I could install ie8 on windows 8, you need to delete ie10, restart and install ie8, don't remember the nuances.